# Embedded ES instance failing when running unit tests

Tags: scala, unit-testing, elasticsearch, specs2, elastic4s

I currently have the following code.
The following is setting up a local elasticsearch instance using the elastic4s library

```
val essettings = Settings
  .settingsBuilder().put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch")
  .put("path.home", "/tmp/v").build()

ElasticsearchConnection.setInstance(ElasticClient.local(essettings))

val mockESItem1 = Map("title" -> "Worth It",
  "artist" -> "Fifth Harmony",
  "countries" -> Seq("AI", "CA", "IT", "AU", "GB", "IO", "IE", "GI", "US", "SH", "MS", "KY"),
  "thumbnails" -> Seq(Map("default" -> "http://cache.vevo.com/Content/VevoImages/video/WRONGVEVOPICTURE.jpg")),
  "videoId" -> "VEVOID1", 
  "videoType" -> "type", 
  "ytVideoId" -> "YTID1", 
  "features" -> Seq(),
  "duration" -> 230)
```

Here I am creating a new index and then inserting the mockES item above.

```
client.execute( create index "videos" shards 1 replicas 5 mappings(
  "video" as (
    "artist" typed StringType,
    "title" typed StringType,
    "countries" typed StringType,
    "thumbnails" typed ObjectType,
    "videoId" typed StringType,
    "videoType" typed StringType,
    "ytVideoId" typed StringType,
    "features" typed StringType,
    "duration" typed IntegerType
    )
  )
)

client.execute(
  bulk(
    index into "videos"/"video" id 1 fields mockESItem1
  )
).await
```

However if I then run a query to find that item in any of my tests, similar to the following:

```
es.execute {
  search in "videos" / "video" limit 5 query bool {
    must(
      queryStringQuery("Worth It").field("title"),
      queryStringQuery("Fifth Harmony").field("artist").field("features"),
      matchQuery("videoType","type"),
      matchQuery("countries","US")
    )
  }
}.await
```

The program breaks with the following error:

```
org.elasticsearch.action.NoShardAvailableActionException: null
at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.start(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:151) [elasticsearch-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction.doExecute(TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction.java:64) [elasticsearch-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction.doExecute(TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction.java:53) [elasticsearch-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
...
org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException: all shards failed
at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.onFirstPhaseResult(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:228) ~[elasticsearch-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.start(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:151) ~[elasticsearch-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction.doExecute(TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction.java:64) ~[elasticsearch-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction.doExecute(TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction.java:53) ~[elasticsearch-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
```

I've been trying to find a solution to this issue off and on for a few days and haven't been able to find anything that helps me solve this issue, so now looking to see if anyone on SE has had similar issues and found a fix.

### UPDATE

I've rewritten what I have so it's a much simpler example, since previous there were still a couple classes from my own code that I was using.

```
import com.sksamuel.elastic4s.ElasticClient
import com.sksamuel.elastic4s.ElasticDsl._
import com.sksamuel.elastic4s.mappings.FieldType.{IntegerType, ObjectType, StringType}
import org.elasticsearch.action.delete.DeleteRequest
import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings
import org.scalatest._
class ESTest extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
  val essettings = Settings
    .settingsBuilder().put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch")
    .put("path.home", "/tmp/v").build()

  val client = ElasticClient.local(essettings)

  val mockESItem1 = Map("title" -> "Worth It",
    "artist" -> "Fifth Harmony",
    "countries" -> Seq("AI", "CA", "IT", "AU", "GB", "IO", "IE", "GI", "US", "SH", "MS", "KY"),
    "thumbnails" -> Seq(Map("default" -> "http://cache.vevo.com/Content/VevoImages/video/WRONGVEVOPICTURE.jpg")),
    "videoId" -> "VEVOID1",
    "videoType" -> "type",
    "ytVideoId" -> "YTID1",
    "features" -> Seq(),
    "duration" -> 230)

  client.execute(create index "videos" shards 1 replicas 5 mappings (
    "video" as(
      "artist" typed StringType,
      "title" typed StringType,
      "countries" typed StringType,
      "thumbnails" typed ObjectType,
      "videoId" typed StringType,
      "videoType" typed StringType,
      "ytVideoId" typed StringType,
      "features" typed StringType,
      "duration" typed IntegerType
      )
    )
  ).await


  val exists = client.execute {
    index exists "videos"
  }.await.isExists

  println(exists)
  println(mockESItem1.get("videoId").get)

  client.execute(
    index into "videos" / "video" id mockESItem1.get("videoId").get fields mockESItem1
  ).await
  println("hi")

  val resp = client.execute {
    search in "videos" / "video" limit 5 query bool {
      must(
        matchQuery("videoType", "type"),
        matchQuery("countries", "US")
      )
    }
  }.await

  println(resp.hits.head.sourceAsString)
  client.client.delete(new DeleteRequest("videos"))
  client.close
}
```

Currently if you run this it will fail to execute the bulk insert, then receive the `NoShardAvailableActionException` when the "test" tries to run the search. Could this be an issue caused by specs2?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in 1.7.4 (if using 2.0+ change ImmutableSettings to Settings):

```
object Test extends App {

  import ElasticDsl._

  val essettings = ImmutableSettings
    .settingsBuilder().put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch")
    .put("path.home", "/tmp/v").build()

  val client = ElasticClient.local(essettings)

  val mockESItem1 = Map("title" -> "Worth It",
    "artist" -> "Fifth Harmony",
    "countries" -> Seq("AI", "CA", "IT", "AU", "GB", "IO", "IE", "GI", "US", "SH", "MS", "KY"),
    "thumbnails" -> Seq(Map("default" -> "http://cache.vevo.com/Content/VevoImages/video/WRONGVEVOPICTURE.jpg")),
    "videoId" -> "VEVOID1",
    "videoType" -> "type",
    "ytVideoId" -> "YTID1",
    "features" -> Seq(),
    "duration" -> 230)

  client.execute(create index "videos" shards 1 replicas 5 mappings (
    "video" as(
      "artist" typed StringType,
      "title" typed StringType,
      "countries" typed StringType,
      "thumbnails" typed ObjectType,
      "videoId" typed StringType,
      "videoType" typed StringType,
      "ytVideoId" typed StringType,
      "features" typed StringType,
      "duration" typed IntegerType
      )
    )
  )

  client.execute(
    bulk(
      index into "videos" / "video" id 1 fields mockESItem1
    )
  ).await

  val resp = client.execute {
    search in "videos" / "video" limit 5 query bool {
      must(
        matchQuery("videoType", "type"),
        matchQuery("countries", "US")
      )
    }
  }.await

  println(resp.hits.head.sourceAsString)
  sys.exit(0)
}
```

Since this is your code with the parts you missed out added in, I can only assume your error is in some of the code you are not showing (like `ElasticsearchConnection`). I also adjusted your query slightly.

Comment: I have an updated set of code without any custom "fluff" from my actual tests. This is using elasticsearch 2.0. I'm still receiving the `NoShardAvailableActionException`, it looks like this is possibly due to no index being created? Then that would explain why it's failing to insert items and find anything. I don't know why the index wouldn't be created though.

Comment: Yes possiblly. Put a .await after your create index call.

Comment: Added an await, also wrapped the insert in a try catch and am doing single insert instead of bulk (updated the code in my question). I am catching a 10 second futures timeout now. However adding the .await did seem to fix the NoShardsAvailable issue, since now I do not get that exception.

Comment: I changed the update code to a barebones test. I am creating the index and then checking to make sure it exists, which it does. It is never getting to the println("hi") line however, due to a 10 second futures timeout. Any thoughts on why this is?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem: subsequent test runs failed with a NoShardAvailableActionException when I tested on an in-memory Elasticsearch node. As I realized that this only happened when the tests were run for 2 or more times my solution was to delete the old index. Roughly, I did:

```
if (testsDoRunInInternalMode()) {
  client.admin().indices().delete(new DeleteIndexRequest(myIndex)).actionGet();
}
```

Maybe that helps.